# SQL server View - loop help (while loop)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, while-loop

I've been asked to produce a dataset using a view in SQL and have a number of products (eg 'a a','b b','c c') and I want to work out totals over 5 years (1,2,3,4,5) and output the totals as total_a_a_yr1, total_b_b_yr1....(see the below code)

Rather than writing out loads of lines of code is there a more efficient way of coding?

I thought about creating a procedure but I don't think you can use an EXEC within a view. I may be wrong. A while loop might be the way to go but I'm unsure about using declares in views.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
,sum(case when product = 'a a' and floor(datediff(dd, date1,date2)/365.25)<1  
                        then amount_received else null end) as total_a_a_yr1

,sum(case when product = 'a a' and floor(datediff(dd, date1,date2)/365.25)<(2) 
                        then amount_received else null end) as total_a_a_yr2

,sum(case when product = 'a a' and floor(datediff(dd, date1,date2)/365.25)<(3)
                        then amount_received else null end) as total_a_a_yr3

,sum(case when product = 'a a' and floor(datediff(dd, date1,date2)/365.25)<(4) 
                        then amount_received else null end) as total_a_a_yr4    

,sum(case when product = 'a a' and floor(datediff(dd, date1,date2/365.25)<(5) 
                        then amount_received else null end) as total_a_a_yr5
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Comment: I don't know what the down vote was for - this is a good question. Up-vote from me for the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, the default value for a case statement is NULL so, "ELSE NULL" is not necessary. Second, this formula is probably not doing exactly what you think: `floor(datediff(dd, date1,date2)/365.25)`. What I mean is, if you are operating under the assumption that there is a leap year every four years, you are incorrect. Leap years don't happen on years divisible by 100 UNLESS it can also be divided by 400. I could be misunderstanding what you're trying to do however.

You're correct, You can't use dynamic SQL (e.g. `EXEC '<sql code>'`) in a view. There's very little you ***can't*** do with a [tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/). Here's how you'd generate your code programatically using a tally table (I'm going to 1 to 100):

```
with yourExpression(ex) as
(
  select ',sum(case when product = ''''a a'''' and floor(datediff(dd, date1,date2)/365.25)<
                        then amount_received else null end) as total_a_a_yr'
),
iTally(N) as
(
  select top(100) cast(row_number() over (order by (select null)) as varchar(3))
  from sys.all_columns
)
select stuff(ex,78,0,'('+N+')')+N
from iTally
cross join yourExpression;
```

You can copy/paste and execute the query as is; it will return:

```
,sum(case when product = ''a a'' and floor(datediff(dd, date1,date2)/365.25)<(1)
                            then amount_received else null end) as total_a_a_yr1
,sum(case when product = ''a a'' and floor(datediff(dd, date1,date2)/365.25)<(2)
                            then amount_received else null end) as total_a_a_yr2
,sum(case when product = ''a a'' and floor(datediff(dd, date1,date2)/365.25)<(3)....
--<truncated for brevity> ... as total_a_a_yr100
```